# Удаление определенного символа в строке по шаблону

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть проблема в написании запроса на sql. Суть проблемы в следующем:
есть заполненная таблица со столбцом FILE_NAME, в этом столбце необходимо в некоторых элементах удалить цифру 0 в строке. Этот 0 всегда находится в одном месте строки. Ниже прикрепляю скриншот с данными, желтым выделены символы, которые необходимо удалить. Находил на просторах интернета функцию regexp_replace, но не очень понял как ей воспользоваться.

[image: скриншот проблемы]

Answer (score 0):

Если верно понял условие отбора то:
REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name,’0(?=\d{3}_\d{3}$)’,’’)

Comment: При написании следующего запроса для проверки:
SELECT regexp_replace(FILE_NAME,'0(?=\d{3}_\d{3}$)','') as FILE_NAME_CORRECT, FILE_NAME
FROM [TABLE] 
Возвращает следующее исключение: 
Сообщение 195, уровень 15, состояние 10, строка 1
'regexp_replace' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Нужно было хотяб указать СУБД, а то я не экстрасенс, ведь сами указали что смотрели про regexp_replace. А ваше решение могло бы быть куда короче если бы использовали данный шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.

Ответ:

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
<p>SET FILE_NAME = substring(FILE_NAME,0,9) + substring(FILE_NAME, 10,len(FILE_NAME))
<p>WHERE (FILE_NAME LIKE('[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
```